# Facing issues in Backbone With Rails 3.x, for multiple routers

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript, backbone-routing

In one of the rails app I am trying to use backbone with "rails-backbone" gem, 
And I have created one model using scaffolding which is working fine.
but I have another model and I am trying to use different router for it, but when tries to instantiate that router from index.html.erb it fires,
**"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"** which clearly means there is no such router. But it is there and even in developer's tool it shows those JS files. I tried all different ways but it didn't work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess that you're defining your router like this:

```
class SomeRouter extends Backbone.Router
  # router code goes here
```

and then you're trying to create one with:

```
r = new SomeRouter
```

But CoffeeScript will wrap your files in a [function to prevent scope creep](http://coffeescript.org/#lexical-scope):

> Although suppressed within this documentation for clarity, all CoffeeScript output is wrapped in an anonymous function:  `(function(){ ... })();` This safety wrapper, combined with the automatic generation of the `var` keyword, make it exceedingly difficult to pollute the global namespace by accident.
>
> If you'd like to create top-level variables for other scripts to use, attach them as properties on **window**, or on the **exports** object in CommonJS. The **existential operator** (covered below), gives you a reliable way to figure out where to add them; if you're targeting both CommonJS and the browser: `exports ? this`

That wrapper will hide `SomeRouter` inside a function so there will be no `SomeRouter` visible outside the file which defines it.

A common solution in Rails/Backbone apps is to manage the namespaces yourself. Set up your own namespace somewhere before any other (Java|Coffee)Script will be pulled in:

```
# AppName is just a placeholder, you'd use something more
# sensible in real life.
window.AppName =
    Routers:     { }
    Views:       { }
    Models:      { }
    Collections: { }
```

and then define your router as:

```
class AppName.Routers.SomeRouter extends Backbone.Router
    #...
```

and later:

```
r = new AppName.Routers.SomeRouter
```

similarly with models, collections, and views that need to be globally visible.

Comment: Thanks it gave me the way.